# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and simultaneous POST and GET

Tags: php, http

When I use `POST` and `GET` requests at the same time, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is set to just POST.

Why is this? Is it because all requests are considered `GET` in any case?

This is the request I made for the purpose of this question.

```
a = $("#AdminAddForm").serialize();
jQuery.post('index.php?test=yes', a);
```

Both $_POST and $_GET are populated after this request, and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] set to POST.

Comment: This is in my opinion a good source: [Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039). Mind that asking for opinions is off-topic on SO.

Comment: _"When I use POST and GET"_ - please show the relevant code where you do this.

Comment: Why do you consider this asking for an opinion? I want to understand the subject, I am assuming there is one true answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP protocol has a first line that is called the "request line". A post looks like this:

```
POST http://website.com/route/whatever HTTP/1.1

... (post body)
```

Notice the mandatory empty line between the request line and the post body.

Now, when you also have a query string like this:

```
POST http://website.com/route/whatever?q=hello HTTP/1.1

... (post body)
```

You're mixing these things:

- the method POST;
- the body of the POST (containing the form's content);
- the query string.

The HTTP request *IS* a POST but in PHP the stuff in the query string will end up in the $_GET global variable nonetheless.

You can have GET parameters in a HTTP POST because the HTTP protocol allows to mix the POST body with the query string.

Answer (score 4):

> When I use POST and GET requests at the same time

This is impossible.

You are, probably, making a POST request that has a query string on the URL.

PHP will populate `$_GET` with data from the query string, but this has absolutely nothing to do with the request method. It is just one of PHP's weird (wrong) naming conventions.

Comment: For the porpose of testing I let a form POST data and used the target index.php?test=yes, which I could read with $_GET.

Comment: @Lexib0y — That's a POST request with a query string in the URL. Nothing to do with GET at all. Just PHP giving stupid names to things `$_GET` should be called `$_QUERY`.

Comment: When there is only a query in the URL, it isn't called a GET in HTTP?

Comment: @Lexib0y — No. A GET request is when the Request Line of the request specifies GET as the method. There are plenty of HTTP requests you could make which aren't GET, don't have a body and have a query string on the URL (such as a DELETE request).

Comment: I will study the subject. In PHP itself you can get by without this knowledge, but I prefer to know at least something about the subject.